# erro com validação de input

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

o seguinte código foi implementado à partir de uma pergunta que achei aqui no sistema

```
$('form input[type="text"]').on('input', function() {
    var inputempty = false;
    $('form > input').each(function() {
        if($(this).val() == '') {
            inputempty = true; } });

    if(inputempty) {
        $('form input[type="submit"]').attr('style', 'background: red');
    } else {
        $('form input[type="submit"]').removeAttr('style'); } });
```

o problema é que não consigo fazer com que ele leia todos os inputs dentro do form, ele somente consegue detectar o primeiro input, estou utilizando jquery 1.8.3 e jquery ui 1.11.4

segue estrutura html

```
    <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($siteuri); ?>" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="contacts_form_name" placeholder="Nome do contato" autofocus />
        <input type="text" name="contacts_form_a[1]" placeholder="Nome do campo" tabindex="1" />
        <input type="text" name="contacts_form_b[1]" placeholder="Valor do campo" tabindex="2" />
        <div id="contacts_form">
Aqui dentro são inseridos inputs com jquery
</div>
        <div id="contacts_form_add" class="cursor_pointer">+</div>
        <input class="cursor_pointer" type="submit" name="contact_send" value="Salvar" />
    </form>
```

e segue o jquery

```
var scntDiv = $('#contacts_form');
var rscn = $('#contacts_form x').size() + 1;
$('#contacts_form_add').live('click', function() {
    $('<x><input type="text" id="focus' + rscn +'" name="contacts_form_a[' + rscn +']" placeholder="Nome do campo" /><input type="text" name="contacts_form_b[' + rscn +']" placeholder="Valor do campo" /><span id="contacts_form_rem" class="cursor_pointer">X</span></x>').appendTo(scntDiv);
    $('#focus'+ rscn).focus();
    rscn++;
    inputattr();
    return false; });

$('#contacts_form_rem').live('click', function() {
    if(rscn > 1) {
    $(this).parents('x').remove();
    rscn--; }
return false; });
```

Comment: Qual é a estrutura do teu HTML?

Comment: a estrutura são inputs dinâmicos, tenho uma função jquery que insere inputs dentro de uma div, mas mesmo com inputs fora deste bloco ele só lê o primeiro

Comment: O que te dá `alert($('form > input').length);` se colocares na primeira linha antes de `var inputempty = false;`?

Comment: aparece apenas o número 4 em todos os inputs, porém só o primeiro input que faz o submit ficar vermelho

Comment: aparece apenas o número 4 em todos os inputs, e não sei o que aconteceu, mas aparentemente está funcionando agora, eu removi o código, ai pus novamente para testar o que você pediu, acho que está funcionando.

Comment: realmente, está funcionando nos 3 primeiros inputs, não sei o que aconteceu, muito esquisito mesmo, porém, os inputs dinâmicos não estão recebendo a função, será que é por que estão dentro de uma div dentro de uma tag? #contacts_form > x > input[type="text"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

acho que descobri, não sei se é o correto, mas parece funcionar

```
$('form input[type="text"]').on('input', function() {
    var inputempty = false;
    $('form > input').each(function() {
        if($(this).val() == '') {
            inputempty = true; } });
    $('form > div > x > input').each(function() {
        if($(this).val() == '') {
            inputempty = true; } });
    if(inputempty) {
        $('form input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
        $('form input[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled'); } });
```

e adicionar este no att

```
$('form input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Comment: Já testaste com `$('form input')` somente, em vez de usar `>`?

Comment: eita, não é que funciona, que mancada, mas, ainda não entendi por que quando fiz a pergunta, não funcionava de forma alguma, nem com > nem sem, mas agora está funcionando, isso é muito esquisito